# creating a for loop that creates a list that doubles the values of the original list

Tags: python, list

Given this array:
`<arr = [[111,2],[3,4],9]>`

I am trying to get this one line of code to work:
`print([[x*2 for x in y if isinstance(y,list)]for y in arr])`
It raises an error: int object is not iterable

I tried it the longer way and it worked:

```
arr2=[]
for y in arr:
    if isinstance(y,list):
        temp_list = []
        for x in y:
            temp_list.append(x*2)
        arr2.append(temp_list)
    else:
        arr2.append(y*2)
print(arr2)
```

Please help me understand why the one liner piece is crashing?

Comment: also is there a better approach to do what I am trying to do? somehow using lambda for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the one-liner code is not working is probably because you use a double bracket when writing your comprehension.
try:
print([x*2 for x in y if isinstance(y,list)]for y in arr])

Comment: I'm glad that works. please mark it as the right answer for other people that might have the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: my rank is so low that im not allowed to upvote ... rip, but i did mark it now

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but in the longer version you  checked for isinstance before doing for x in y - in the shorter one you did for x in y first the isinstance (i might  be wrong - i cant boot u python rn)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).